# bracket usage dilemma

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

If I include a reference at the end of a sentence where it is already included in a bracketed phrase, do you put one or two brackets to close?
E.g.

> Goldilocks and her friend found that bears were not as friendly as she had been told (her father had previously reported that they were always tame (Bruno, 2019)).

Is the double bracket correct - I feel it should be a single bracket that closes both in one with a fullstop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brackets within brackets](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493096/brackets-within-brackets)

Comment: I'd like to say it's a duplicate, because both questions mention references. However, this question specifically asks about whether two closing brackets are necessary, and the answer on the other question talks about using square brackets.